# Data type LVARCHAR corruption after recovering data

Tags: sql, encoding, informix, sqldatatypes

I face the following problem :

I deleted a key in a table (wrongly) and then I recovered the whole table through this way:

```
LOAD FROM 'C:\db\rqrequesttrans.dat' delimiter '~' insert into rqrequesttrans
```

---

Nearly everything is okay, but I get data corrupted in an `LVARCHAR` field:

For example:

`<p>ääÊãÑå ÈÇäÊæÈ ÈÇääÇÒå.</p>` instead of `<p>للتكرم بالتنبيه باللازم.</p>`

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an answer; it is some analysis, and a request for a lot more information.

#### Analysis

The Arabic data appears in my browser as UTF-8:

```
0x3C = U+003C
0x70 = U+0070
0x3E = U+003E
0xD9 0x84 = U+0644
0xD9 0x84 = U+0644
0xD8 0xAA = U+062A
0xD9 0x83 = U+0643
0xD8 0xB1 = U+0631
0xD9 0x85 = U+0645
0x20 = U+0020
0xD8 0xA8 = U+0628
0xD8 0xA7 = U+0627
0xD9 0x84 = U+0644
0xD8 0xAA = U+062A
0xD9 0x86 = U+0646
0xD8 0xA8 = U+0628
0xD9 0x8A = U+064A
0xD9 0x87 = U+0647
0x20 = U+0020
0xD8 0xA8 = U+0628
0xD8 0xA7 = U+0627
0xD9 0x84 = U+0644
0xD9 0x84 = U+0644
0xD8 0xA7 = U+0627
0xD8 0xB2 = U+0632
0xD9 0x85 = U+0645
0x2E = U+002E
0x3C = U+003C
0x2F = U+002F
0x70 = U+0070
0x3E = U+003E
```

The other data appears as UTF8-encoded characters from ISO 8859-1 (or 8859-15):

```
0x3C = U+003C
0x70 = U+0070
0x3E = U+003E
0xC3 0xA4 = U+00E4
0xC3 0xA4 = U+00E4
0xC3 0x8A = U+00CA
0xC3 0xA3 = U+00E3
0xC3 0x91 = U+00D1
0xC3 0xA5 = U+00E5
0x20 = U+0020
0xC3 0x88 = U+00C8
0xC3 0x87 = U+00C7
0xC3 0xA4 = U+00E4
0xC3 0x8A = U+00CA
0xC3 0xA6 = U+00E6
0xC3 0x88 = U+00C8
0x20 = U+0020
0xC3 0x88 = U+00C8
0xC3 0x87 = U+00C7
0xC3 0xA4 = U+00E4
0xC3 0xA4 = U+00E4
0xC3 0x87 = U+00C7
0xC3 0x92 = U+00D2
0xC3 0xA5 = U+00E5
0x2E = U+002E
0x3C = U+003C
0x2F = U+002F
0x70 = U+0070
0x3E = U+003E
```

We can see the `<p>` and `.</p>` data is common, and the blanks U+0020 appear in the same places.

Aligning the data blocks, we can some some consistency and inconsistency:

```
0xD9 0x84 = U+0644  :  0xC3 0xA4 = U+00E4   Delta = 0x0560
0xD9 0x84 = U+0644  :  0xC3 0xA4 = U+00E4   Delta = 0x0560
0xD8 0xAA = U+062A  :  0xC3 0x8A = U+00CA   Delta = 0x0560
0xD9 0x83 = U+0643  :  0xC3 0xA3 = U+00E3   Delta = 0x0560
0xD8 0xB1 = U+0631  :  0xC3 0x91 = U+00D1   Delta = 0x0560
0xD9 0x85 = U+0645  :  0xC3 0xA5 = U+00E5   Delta = 0x0560
0x20      = U+0020  :  0x20      = U+0020

0xD8 0xA8 = U+0628  :  0xC3 0x88 = U+00C8   Delta = 0x0560
0xD8 0xA7 = U+0627  :  0xC3 0x87 = U+00C7   Delta = 0x0560
0xD9 0x84 = U+0644  :  0xC3 0xA4 = U+00E4   Delta = 0x0560
0xD8 0xAA = U+062A  :  0xC3 0x8A = U+00CA   Delta = 0x0560
0xD9 0x86 = U+0646  :  0xC3 0xA6 = U+00E6   Delta = 0x0560
0xD8 0xA8 = U+0628  :  0xC3 0x88 = U+00C8   Delta = 0x0560
0xD9 0x8A = U+064A
0xD9 0x87 = U+0647
0x20      = U+0020  :  0x20      = U+0020

0xD8 0xA8 = U+0628  :  0xC3 0x88 = U+00C8   Delta = 0x0560
0xD8 0xA7 = U+0627  :  0xC3 0x87 = U+00C7   Delta = 0x0560
0xD9 0x84 = U+0644  :  0xC3 0xA4 = U+00E4   Delta = 0x0560
0xD9 0x84 = U+0644  :  0xC3 0xA4 = U+00E4   Delta = 0x0560
0xD8 0xA7 = U+0627  :  0xC3 0x87 = U+00C7   Delta = 0x0560
0xD8 0xB2 = U+0632  :  0xC3 0x92 = U+00D2   Delta = 0x0560
0xD9 0x85 = U+0645  :  0xC3 0xA5 = U+00E5   Delta = 0x0560
```

So, clearly, there was a problem somewhere along the line.  Most likely there was an issue with code sets.  The constant 0x0560 isn't significant that I know of, apart from the fact that where the character codes are correct and incorrect, that is the magic number.

#### Questions

No-one is going to be able to give you much help without a lot of answers to a lot of questions.  Of course, there's a distinct possibility that some of the answers will make some of the questions moot.

1. Which platform are you running on?  (O/S name and version; CPU type.)  Given the load file name, you are most likely running some version of Windows.  Is it Win32 or Win64?  And which version of Windows?
2. Which version of Informix are you using?  (For example, Informix 11.70.FC7W2.)
3. What is the locale (DB_LOCALE) of the database you are working with?  (Example: en_us.8859-1.)
4. What is the client locale (CLIENT_LOCALE)?
5. How was the data file `C:\db\rqrequesttrans.dat` created?  Were the locale settings the same?
6. What are the bytes in that file where the example data came from?
7. Did you execute the LOAD command in DB-Access or something else?  If something else, what?
8. How big is the data file?
9. What is the schema of the table?
10. How many rows are there in the table?
11. Is the corruption in the LVARCHAR field consistent across rows?
12. Are you able to do a page dump for the data pages containing the table?  (`oncheck -pp` or `oncheck -pP`, probably)
13. Do you have a support contract with IBM?  If so, use it — it will be quicker by far.

Ideally, you'd demonstrate the corruption in a small table — one with a small subset of the columns of the full data (2 or 3 columns, one of them being the LVARCHAR column), and a small number of rows (under 10).  We may not be so lucky as to be able to create that.  The questions listed are likely to be the first ones that are asked (except perhaps the `oncheck` information).

Comment: We're going to need to know whether you're using the system correctly or are in fact misusing the system.  Unfortunately, there are lots of ways people misuse the system, sometimes intentionally, more usually unintentionally.  And when all goes right, then everyone is happy enough.  When something goes wrong, understanding how the system is being (mis)used is one aspect of sorting out what the status quo ante was, so that we can get back to that situation.

Comment: One advantage of going to the Tech Support people is that they're specialists and may be able to resolve things quickly.  I'm a generalist, and don't have the day-to-day knowledge of the issues (especially not on Windows), which means I may eventually get to an answer, but I'll likely go on a circuitous path, not knowing the more direct path.

Comment: I'm grateful to your effort , my team leader import the `.dat` file to excel sheet in(some arabic encoding) and he gets the correct data , but still can't load the field data from the excel sheet :(

Comment: How about the backup or previous Windows restore checkpoints?.. I run Informix for Windows within a virtual hard disk, which allows me to undo the disk in case I screw things up. Thank God for VHD's!